# SSIS ragged file not recognized CRLF

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssis, etl, flat-file

In SSIS, I try to load data from a flat file.
The flat file have fixed width columns, but some column are not present in a row (a column can have a CRLF, which must be a new line) like this

```
a    b      c
the  first  rowok<CRLF>
iu   jjrjdd<CRLF>
this is a   newline<CRLF>
```

How I can have exactly the same number of line and exact data in my output?

I setup a flat file connection, of ragged right type.

In this sample, row 1 is correctly retrieve, but for row 2, it didn't recognize CRLF, and put in b column all the 3rd row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Workaround

1. In the flat file connection manager read the whole line as one Column *(add only one column of type DT_STR and length 4000)*

[image]

2. Then in the dataflow task add a script component
3. Add three output column (a,b,c) of type `DT_STR`

[image]

4. write a script that split each row and put values in columns (if one value is missed then null) *(i used vb.net)*

*Tab delimited columns*

```
    Public Overrides Sub Input0_ProcessInputRow(ByVal Row As Input0Buffer)


        If Not Row.Column0_IsNull AndAlso
                Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Row.Column0.Trim) Then

            Dim str() As String = Row.Column0.Split(CChar(vbTab))


            If str.Length >= 3 Then

                Row.a = str(0)
                Row.b = str(1)
                Row.c = str(2)

            ElseIf str.Length = 2 Then

                Row.a = str(0)
                Row.b = str(1)
                Row.c_IsNull = True

            ElseIf str.Length = 1 Then


                Row.a = str(0)
                Row.b_IsNull = True
                Row.c_IsNull = True



            Else

                Row.a_IsNull = True
                Row.b_IsNull = True
                Row.c_IsNull = True


            End If




        Else

            Row.a_IsNull = True
            Row.b_IsNull = True
            Row.c_IsNull = True

        End If


    End Sub
```

*Fixed width columns*

```
Public Overrides Sub Input0_ProcessInputRow(ByVal Row As Input0Buffer)


    If Not Row.Column0_IsNull AndAlso
                Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Row.Column0.Trim) Then

        'Assuming that
        'Col a => 0-5
        'Col b => 5-15
        'Col c => 15-

        Dim intlength As Integer = Row.Column0.Length



        If intlength <= 5 Then

            Row.a = Row.Column0
            Row.b_IsNull = True
            Row.c_IsNull = True

        ElseIf intlength > 5 AndAlso intlength <= 15 Then


            Row.a = Row.Column0.Substring(0, 5)
            Row.b = Row.Column0.Substring(5, 10)
            Row.c_IsNull = True

        ElseIf intlength > 15 Then

            Row.a = Row.Column0.Substring(0, 5)
            Row.b = Row.Column0.Substring(5, 10)
            Row.c = Row.Column0.Substring(15)

        End If



    Else

        Row.a_IsNull = True
        Row.b_IsNull = True
        Row.c_IsNull = True

    End If


End Sub
```

*You can also achieve this using derived column transformation*

Comment: Hi Hadi,
thanks for your feedback. As the files contains about 40 columns, and can have 150 rows, I create a flat file connection manager of delimited type, with only one column. And as you recommend, I will use a derived column to retrieve data.
Thanks to you.
Regards,

Comment: @Cascador84 if this answer solved ur isuue u have to accept it.And also if you find it helpful u have to upvote it. Happy to help